# Odd behaviour with HtmlHelper and css class

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I was just working on an MVC view and I came across some odd behaviour.

In my view I had the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Uprn, new { @class = "hidden"} )
```

The output was

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select an address" id="Uprn" name="Uprn" type="text" value="">
```

When I changed my view to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Uprn, new { @class = "hidden"} )
```

the output was

```
<input class="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select an address" id="Uprn" name="Uprn" type="text" value="">
```

As you can see in the first instance it ignored my class name for the element, but in the second it didn't!

Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: It entirely depends on the code of the editor partial view you have defined for your `Uprn` class. Can you post the code of that?

Comment: Uprn is a string property 

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select an address")]
  [Display(Name = "UPRN")]
  public string Uprn { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. You must use templates to assign HTML attributes to EditorFor but you can assign to TextBoxFor with the given syntax.